# Animate UIView (when Drawing on UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext)

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

I created a class that draws a single-bar-chart that indicates a percent value, when one is set. How can I animate the bar, so that it grows from the left to the right?

The animate-function that I already have does not work like it want it to...

```
class EasyLineView : UIView {

    var fillRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    var percentValue: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    var orientation: BarOrientation = .vertical

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        print("drawing with \(rect.size.width)")

        let r = self.bounds // the view's bounds

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() // get the current context

        ctx!.setFillColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor) // set fill color to the given color if it's provided, else use clearColor

        if (self.orientation == .vertical){
            fillRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: r.size.width, height: percentValue*r.size.height)

        } else {
            fillRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: percentValue*r.size.width, height: r.size.height)
        }

        ctx!.fill(fillRect)

    }

// does not work
func animate(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, animations: {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it like that. Drawing a box in `draw(_:)` will give you poor performance and no flexibility for animations.

If all you want is an animatable box whose size you can configure, add a subview and set the background colour to your drawing colour. Then you can use autolayout or manual frame setting, in an animation block, to make the box animate to the size you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, jrturton! However, I have one other question regarding your recommended approach: when I use the draw-function, I can access the width of the view, since it's auto layout constraints (e.g. pinnend to left and right end of the screen) have already been applied. However, when I want to set the bar in the class for its subview, and want to use self.frame.width, I get 0 - do you know why?

Comment: You're probably trying to access it before the view has been laid out. However, you could just use constraints, for example pin the bar to the leading, top and bottom edges then give it a width constraint which is a multiplier of the width of the superview

Comment: thanks for your input! I now updated the progress bar in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and its finally working :)